# space points in a scatter plot in R

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I am plotting a scatter plot in R, however I have many data points and they overlap. I want to have a plot where there no overlaps and maintain a reasonable size of the data . [This is the image of the scatter. On the top side is where the data are clustered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8zml.png)
This is the code `plot(data2,col="red",pch=21,cex=0.7)`

Answer (score 0):

Could you put a reproducible code to check.

One thing you can do is may be increase the space between y axis interval.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.